# spark-submit cluster mode not working for python spark but working for scala spark

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-spark-2.0, spark-submit

I have a cluster where we have hadoop setup with spark integrated. The spark version is spark v2.0.0 and when you deploy a scala spark in cluster mode its working as expected.
Following is the command: `spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn /usr/local/spark-bkp-24apr/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar`

However, when I try to trigger the spark-submit with pyspark, its failing with the following error:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test.py
19/02/14 15:59:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxx.xxx.xxx/10.250.36.240:8032
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 19 NodeManagers
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
19/02/14 15:59:25 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
19/02/14 15:59:25 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/02/14 15:59:31 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-8b9d5766-0458-430d-a4a8-43f143c032fe/__spark_libs__8961544755566009185.zip -> hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/user/ecomm/.sparkStaging/application_1539572182703_0803/__spark_libs__8961544755566009185.zip
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/ecomm/test.py -> hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/user/ecomm/.sparkStaging/application_1539572182703_0803/test.py
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/user/ecomm/.sparkStaging/application_1539572182703_0803/pyspark.zip
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip -> hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/user/ecomm/.sparkStaging/application_1539572182703_0803/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-8b9d5766-0458-430d-a4a8-43f143c032fe/__spark_conf__1991403966415671421.zip -> hdfs://xxx.xxx.xxx:9000/user/ecomm/.sparkStaging/application_1539572182703_0803/__spark_conf__.zip
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ecomm
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ecomm
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ecomm); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ecomm); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1539572182703_0803 to ResourceManager
19/02/14 15:59:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1539572182703_0803
19/02/14 15:59:35 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:35 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: N/A
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1550131174756
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/proxy/application_1539572182703_0803/
         user: ecomm
19/02/14 15:59:36 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:37 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:38 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:39 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:40 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:41 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:45 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:48 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:50 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:51 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:52 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:53 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:54 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:55 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:56 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:57 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:58 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 15:59:59 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:00 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:01 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:02 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:03 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:04 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:05 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:06 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:07 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:08 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:09 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:10 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:11 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:13 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/02/14 16:00:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1539572182703_0803 (state: FAILED)
19/02/14 16:00:17 INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1539572182703_0803 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1539572182703_0803_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/cluster/app/application_1539572182703_0803Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1539572182703_0803_02_000001
Exit code: 127
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1550131174756
         final status: FAILED
         tracking URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/cluster/app/application_1539572182703_0803
         user: ecomm
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1539572182703_0803 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1132)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1175)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
19/02/14 16:00:17 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/02/14 16:00:17 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-8b9d5766-0458-430d-a4a8-43f143c032fe
```

Still not able to get what am I missing, any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are landing up on this page and if you have configured your own cluster this might help you:
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127 generally relates to script issue.
Kindly check the script and remove any unnecessary arguments.

In my case, I was facing the following issue in my code:

```
/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5 : error while loading shared libraries : 
libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0 : cannot open shared object file : No such file or 
directory
```

Recently we upgraded our cluster python version from 2.7.x to 3.5.x and what I noticed was when jobs ran in client mode, it was running successfully and not in cluster mode.

The reason is, that all the other nodes apart from the edgenode/master node were still running with python 2.7.x configured for the same user.

Once the same settings were deployed into the rest of the nodes for the same user, the issue got resolved and all nodes were showing python 3.5.x.

In .bashrc:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export SPARK_PID_DIR=/data/ecommerce/hadoop-2.7.2/pids/spark#$SPARK_HOME/temp
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export OOZIE_HOME=/data/ecommerce/oozie-server/oozie-4.2.0
export PATH=$PATH:$OOZIE_HOME/bin

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.5
export PATH="/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin":$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64
#export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/spark/python/lib/
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3.5
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Cheers to the downvote, however, hate when comment section is empty. Someone is not having a good day. Please provide the comments before down voting, Feel free to reach out from my bio description